# why some Fault Tolerance settings in Azure Data Factory are disabled?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, fault-tolerance

I am creating an Azure Data factory to copy binary files from the Google Cloud Storage bucket to the Azure Blob Storage container. The files need to be copied without any compression.
I want to specify fault tolerance settings to skip files with invalid names and skip forbidden files but those options are disabled when I create the copy pipeline using Azure portal.

[image]

Source and Sink configurations are as follows

[image]

What are the ways,if I want to use such fault tolerance configurations -

```
 "skipErrorFile": { 
        "fileMissing": true, 
        "fileForbidden": true, 
        "dataInconsistency": true,
        "invalidFileName": true        
    },
```

Tried editing the JSON code representation of the factory, the changes don't reflect after publishing.
Experts, please help.

Answer (score 1):

When I tried to apply fault tolerance, I got the same issue only one option is enabled for me while copying binary data from blob storage to ADLS gen 2.

[image]

**I have added blob data contributor role to the storage account and tried with below source dataset:**

[image]

I tried to apply fault tolerance below three options are enabled:

[image]

As per [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-fault-tolerance)

[image]

So, I have given a folder which is having list files then I was able to enable all options as mentioned below:

[image]

Maku sure you have given all [permissions](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam-roles) to your source dataset.